# Можно ли на одном AnchorPane менять местами Labl(ы)?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: Художник из меня не очень]То есть именно в коде. Просто я-то меняю их местами, то есть можно сказать переключаю слои, в SceneBuilder(e), но мне ведь надо... Короче, прямо в методе initialize можно ли менять местами слои в AnchorPane.
P.s. to front в моём случае не подходит, да и работает он как-то криво...
P.s. боюсь, что с кодом будут проблемы, так как дофига лишнего для вас.., а вот paint - эт можно

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Что вы подразумеваете под "менять местами" просто я-то то есть. Нарисуйте хотя бы в PAINT что вы хотите, и приложите код который вы написали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `initialize` лучше так не делать, может выкинуть `illegal exception`. Я нашёл что-то подобное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761415/how-to-change-order-of-children-in-javafx/22069230)

Ваши манипуляции лучше производить динамически(не в SceneBuilder), до присваивания `getChildren().addAll`